# How to get scatter points for a scatter plot with different colors in accordance to a particular range

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, matplotlib-basemap

hope everyone is doing well in these hard times. I am trying to plot the track of a cyclone with scatter points over a base map. I was successful in plotting it, but what I want is want the scatter plots to be plotted with different colors according to a certain range, such as less than 17 knots in color black, between 17-27 knts blue, between 27-33 cyan, between 33-47 green, between 47-63 orange and greater than 120 knots red. I was able to plot the scatter with various colors but not according to the range. So if anyone can help me by showing me how to do it it will be much appreciated.
The code I have used and the plot generated is attached below.

```
import os
os.environ["PROJ_LIB"] = "C:\\Utilities\\Python\\Anaconda\\Library\\share"; #fixr
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import proplot as plot
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
m=Basemap()
#dt = pd.read_excel('E:/tracks.xlsx',sheet_name='amp')
data = [25,25,35,40,45,55,70,80,100,120,125,130,125,115,105,100,95]
lon= [87,86.3,86.3,86.1,86,86,86,86.1,86.3,86.2,86.3,86.5,86.7,86.9,87,87.2,87.5]
lat= [10.4,10.9,10.9,11.1,11.4,11.5,12,12.5,13.2,13.4,14,14.9,15.6,16.5,17.4,18.4,19.1]
cmap = mpl.cm.get_cmap('bwr')
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=25, vmax=130)
colors = cmap(norm(data))
x,y=m(lon,lat)
fig, axs = plot.subplots(ncols=1, axwidth=3, proj='merc', proj_kw={'lon_0': 180})
axs.format(
latlim=(0, 30), lonlim=(50, 100),linewidth=1,
gridlinewidth=0,coast=True, latlines=30, lonlines=60,)
l=axs.scatter(x,y,c=colors,s=10)
fig.colorbar(colors)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`ListedColormap`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap.html) with [**`BoundaryNorm`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm.html) to generate your custom discrete colorbar. Here is an example using `cartopy`:

```py
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

data = [25,25,35,40,45,55,70,80,100,120,125,130,125,115,105,100,95]
lon = [87,86.3,86.3,86.1,86,86,86,86.1,86.3,86.2,86.3,86.5,86.7,86.9,87,87.2,87.5]
lat = [10.4,10.9,10.9,11.1,11.4,11.5,12,12.5,13.2,13.4,14,14.9,15.6,16.5,17.4,18.4,19.1]

cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['blue', 'cyan', 'green', 'orange'])
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm([17, 27, 33, 47, 63], cmap.N) 
cmap.set_under('black')
cmap.set_over('red')
colors = cmap(norm(data))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5), subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree()})
ax.coastlines() # draw coastlines
ax.set_extent([65, 95, 5, 25]) # zoom into India
ax.scatter(lon, lat, s=20, c=colors, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
fig.colorbar(mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(norm, cmap), extend='both')
```

[image: cartopy with discrete cmap]

Comment: thanks for the help. I did as you stated but getting an error as "ValueError: Input mappable must be a matplotlib artist, list of objects, list of colors, or colormap. Got <matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable object at 0x0000022C61E24B50>."

Comment: @DebashisPaul is that after integrating back to your real code? or you're getting that error with my sample code alone?

Comment: the error is after integrating back to the real code

Comment: ya the sample code works but after integrating with the original code getting the error.

Comment: thanks for the help. Yes, this is how I wanted.

Comment: @DebashisPaul you're welcome! btw i just fixed a small bug (`set_under` and `set_over` need to be *before* `colors = cmap(norm(data))`)